# create a new column with max value of another column

Tags: apache-spark

I have a dataframe called `dates` with column `start_date`.  I want to take the max value of `start_date` and add it as a column to my new dataframe.  I do not want to use any spark actions for this (so no collectAsList and get that value like that).

I know I could do

```
//DatesDF generated by Select Min(start_date) from dates
String minDateValueLiteral = datesDF.as(Encoders.STRING()).collectAsList().get(0);
finalDF = finalDF.withColumn("NEW_COLUMN", functions.lit(minDateValueLiteral))
```

But I don't want to perform a spark action.  How can this be done?

Comment: check if `df.select(col("Start_date"),....,max("start_date"))` works

Comment: `finalDF` is some arbitrary dataframe that is not the `dates` table.    I tried `.withColumn("NEW_COLUMN", datesDF.select(functions.max("start_date")))`  but it threw an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Window function `max`:

```
finalDF.withColumn("NEW_COLUMN", max("start_date").over()).show()
```

**EDIT**

If the dates are in another DataFrame called `datesDF`, you can, first, aggregate max dates and then cross join the resulted DF with your `finalDF` like this :

```
import spark.implicits._
val finalDF = Seq((1, "A"),
                  (2, "B"),
                  (3, "C"),
                  (4, "D"),
                  (5, "E")
              ).toDF("id", "name")

val datesDF = Seq(("2019-12-05"),
                  ("2019-12-04"),
                  ("2019-12-03"),
                  ("2019-12-02"),
                  ("2019-12-01")
                ).toDF("start_date")


val maxDateDF = datesDF.agg(max("start_date").alias("start_date"))

finalDF.crossJoin(maxDateDF).show()
```

Comment: finalDF is already a defined dataframe. I need to append a new column  `max("start_date")` from `datesDF`

Comment: Sorry, I guess I am not expressing myself well enough.. finalDF does not contain the `start_date` column at all or any column similar.  It is only present in the `datesDF` I want to max("start_date") from `datesDF` appended as a new column to `finalDF`